# How I can run a function in parallel and after the main program exits he still continues running?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pygtk

## TL;DR

How I can keep the parallel process running independently of the main using the multiprocessing lib or other way? (the sample code now is using fork)

## Long history

Well, I was writing a little script for back-end to my conky configurations and one of this is a `rss_parser.py`, whose get a set of titles/urls and put on stdout. Recently, I was wondering about something to active new notifications using `Notify` of `GTK` when something new appears on the RSS list.

But I have some problem here. I put a action to open the link, so when my notification is up, I can click and open the browser. That part of the code need waiting the user click or the notifications close to finish, for which is running in a proper event loop. However, this conflicts with other thing: **to update my conky** I need to my main script **finish without expecting the notifications part**! So my idea is put the notifications in parallel.

## The Code from Hell

I tried this with this full code [code](https://gist.github.com/ryukinix/4bdd0eafb26c3073d0b5111c42ea8ec5#file-rss_parser-py-L199): (check the `parallel_notify` function)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
#
#   Python Script
#
#   Copyleft © Manoel Vilela
#
#

import feedparser
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from string import ascii_letters as alphabet
from os import fork
import json
import sys
import webbrowser

import gi
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
from gi.repository import GObject  # noqa
from gi.repository import Notify   # noqa


class RssNotifier(GObject.Object):
    Notify.init("rss_conky")
    notifications = []

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        self.loop = GObject.MainLoop()
        super(RssNotifier, self).__init__()
        GObject.timeout_add(100, self.exit_when_empty)
        # lets initialise with the application name

    def send_notification(self, title, text, url, file_path_to_icon=""):

        n = Notify.Notification.new(title, text, file_path_to_icon)
        # print('put notification')
        self.notifications.append(n)
        n.add_action(url, 'open', self.open_webbrowser)
        n.connect('closed', self.close_notification, n)
        n.show()

    def send_rss(self, rss, url):
        self.send_notification(self.label, rss, url, 'rss')

    def open_webbrowser(self, n, url):
        # print(':: webbrowse opening')
        webbrowser.open(url)

    def close_notification(self, n, arg):
        self.notifications.remove(n)
        # print(':: remove notification')
        # print(':: notifications: ', self.notifications)

    def exit_when_empty(self):
        # print('exit check')
        if not any(RssNotifier.notifications):
            self.loop.quit()
            return False
        return True


CACHE_FILE = '.cache.json'

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '-u', '--url',
    default="http://hackernews.demos.monkeylearn.com/feed.xml?",
    dest='url',
    type=str,
    help='The url to be parsed'
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-l', '--lines',
    default=10,
    dest='lines',
    type=int
)

parser.add_argument(
    '-w', '--width',
    default=80,
    dest='width',
    type=int,
    help='The horizontal limit'
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-p', '--prefix',
    default='- ',
    dest='prefix',
    type=str,
    help='A prefix attached each feed'

)

parser.add_argument(
    '-i', '--ignore',
    default='',
    dest='ignore',
    type=str,
    help='Useless string to remove'
)

parser.add_argument(
    '-n', '--disable-notifications',
    default=True,
    dest='notifications',
    action='store_false',
    help='Disable notifications (default True)'
)

parser.add_argument(
    '-r', '--rss-label',
    default='RSS',
    dest='rss_label',
    type=str,
    help='A simple label for what is fetching'

)


def get_label(entry):
    if entry.get('tags'):
        label = '{}: '.format(entry.get('tags').pop()['term'])
    else:
        label = ''
    return label


def long_title_clean(title):
    if len(title) > options.width:
        return (title[:options.width] + '\n' +
                ' ' * (len(options.prefix)) +
                long_title_clean(title[options.width:].strip()))
    return title


def translate_name(url):
    return '.' + ''.join([x for x in url if x in alphabet]) + '.cache'


def save_cache(new_cache, key):
    cache_file = get_cache_file()
    cache_file[key] = new_cache
    with open(CACHE_FILE, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(cache_file, f)


def get_cache(key):
    return get_cache_file()[key]


def get_cache_text(key):
    return '\n'.join((x for x, _ in get_cache(key)))


def get_cache_file():
    try:
        with open(CACHE_FILE, 'r') as f:
            return json.load(f)
    except:
        return {}


def notify(new_rss):
    notifier = RssNotifier(options.rss_label)
    for rss, url in new_rss:
        notifier.send_rss(rss, url)
    notifier.loop.run()


def ignore_pattern(title):
    return title.replace(options.ignore, '')


def parallel_notifications(new_rss):
    if any(new_rss) and options.notifications:
        if fork() == 0:
            notify(new_rss)


def parse_print_rss(feed):
    new_cache = []
    for entry in feed['entries']:
        if len(new_cache) >= options.lines:
            break
        label = get_label(entry)
        output = '{}{}{!s}'.format(options.prefix, label, entry.title)
        title = long_title_clean(ignore_pattern(output))
        if title not in new_cache:
            new_cache.append([title, entry['link']])
            print(title)

    return new_cache


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = GObject.MainLoop()
    options = parser.parse_args()
    feed = feedparser.parse(options.url)
    keyname = translate_name(options.url)
    if not any(feed['entries']):
        cache = get_cache_text(keyname)
        print(cache)
        sys.exit(0)

    new_cache = parse_print_rss(feed)
    old_cache = get_cache(keyname)
    new_rss = [x for x in new_cache if x not in old_cache]
    new_rss = new_cache  # force use the new_cache
    # the paralell part going here
    parallel_notifications(new_rss)
    save_cache(new_cache, keyname)
```

## The code for lazy persons

```
import os
if os.fork() == 0:
     os.setsid()
     while True:
         pass
print('shorter')
```

ps.: on conky, never 'shorter' is send, because this never happens, he wait for the child! (or something like that)

## Suffered attempt

On the first try, I used **multprocessing** lib to setup a new process as daemon (to the main program not expect finish), but this not works. By the way, this create another problem now: when the main program finish, the Process parallel finish too and now I don't have more notifications (or simple the routine for click doesn't works because the process is already finished)!!! D:

## EDIT-1

Using `fork` works fine if I try running in the terminal! But I have a real problem running in the conky! Why this? In `sublime`, besides, I have just the same behavior: **the parent process only exits when the child exits**.

Comment: Use this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/

Comment: You can give me a example of this use for my problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **daemonize the thread**

The snippet I used to run in other thread, I just put this (as Valentin Lorentz suggest)

```
from daemon import DaemonContext
with DaemonContext():
      paralell_notifications(new_rss)
```

And always works fine, however, only in the terminal and sublime. My main problem, whose is the conky, I still have the same problem. Appears be a bug on the conky.

Why this? Becase as he [said](https://askubuntu.com/a/192142):

> a daemon is a background, non-interactive program. It is detached
>   from the keyboard and display of any interactive user. The word daemon
>   for denoting a background program is from the Unix culture; it is not
>   universal.